# how can i put sprite into PolygonComponent within the borders?

Tags: flutter, 2d, flame

pls help to put sprite inside the borders. The desired result on screen 2. What i have now on scr 1.
Versions
Flutter 3.3.1
Flame   1.3.0

```
      Future<void> onLoad() async {
        super.onLoad();
        size.setValues(cellSize, cellSize);
        //  anchor = Anchor.center;
        PolygonComponent cell = PolygonComponent.relative(
          [
            Vector2(0.0, -1.0),
            Vector2(-1.0, -0.5),
            Vector2(-1.0, 0.5),
            Vector2(0.0, 1.0),
            Vector2(1.0, 0.5),
            Vector2(1.0, -0.5),
          ],
          parentSize: size,
          //angle: 45,
    
          paint: Paint()
            ..color = Colors.white
            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
            ..strokeWidth = 1,
        );
        add(cell);
    
        SpriteComponent sprite = SpriteComponent()
          ..sprite = await Sprite.load('grass_1.png')
          ..size = Vector2(cellSize, cellSize);
    
        cell.add(sprite);
      }
```

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNLvM.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to clip the part that is rendered in the `SpriteComponent`, this is done by extending the `SpriteComponent` and overriding its `render` method.

```
class MyClippedComponent extends SpriteComponent {
  ...
  
  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.clipPath(Your polygon as a path);
    super.render(canvas);
  }
}
```

In the next version of Flame there will be a component that does this for you by adding it as a parent to the component that you want to clip, it's called the `ClipComponent`.

The `ClipComponent` can be used today too if you add Flame as a git dependency and depend on the `main` branch.